# make a difference to/in people's lives

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition is correct in this sentence?
For context: It's a job description and I want to inspire candidates to apply. So, I want to say that "You will have an opportunity to make a difference in/to people's lives."

Google gives me both prepositions. Are both prepositions correct and only have different connotations?

Comment: Both fine. 'To' comes over as slightly more drastic, a change in the direction of one's life (though need not be a huge change). The outside impetus metaphor.  'In' comes over as involving a less major upgrade. The container metaphor.

Comment: If you can't make up your mind, you could just say something like *to improve people's lives* or *to benefit others*.

Comment: Thank you for such quick replies!